# Confusion with `nil` output when using `Symbol#<=>` in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

[***`Symbol#<=>`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Symbol.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)

> simply says: Compares symbol with other_symbol after calling to_s on each of the symbols. Returns -1, 0, +1 or nil depending on whether symbol is less than, equal to, or greater than other_symbol. **`nil` is returned if the two values are incomparable.**

I was trying to understand how `Symbol#<=>` works when returning `nil`. Doing so I played with the code:

```
>> :x.to_s
=> "x"
>> 'x'.to_s
=> "x"
```

From the above `IRB` code I thought the return value will be `0`. But the actual is `nil`. As doc says that before using `<=>` operator `to_s` is applied both the `RHO` and `LHO`. But here the below code is not supporting that principle, seems to me.

```
>> :x <=> "x"
#=> nil
```

So I tried to see the source code,to answer myself:

```
static VALUE
sym_cmp(VALUE sym, VALUE other)
{
    if (!SYMBOL_P(other)) {
        return Qnil;
    }
    return rb_str_cmp_m(rb_sym_to_s(sym), rb_sym_to_s(other));
}
```

Looking at the source code it is clear that if `RHO` is not the object of class `Symbol`, `nil` will be returned. Let's see the something
more in IRB:

```
>> "x" <=> :x
#=> nil
```

Again `nil`. The source code saying that `rb_str_cmp_m(rb_sym_to_s(sym),rb_sym_to_s(other))` will be executed now. So now I went to the see the source code of [***`STRING.C`***](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c). So we are basically pasing the `rb_str_cmp_m(???,"x")`. Now the I found from github:(`?` means don't know what value)

```
rb_str_cmp_m(VALUE str1, VALUE str2)
{
    int result;

    if (!RB_TYPE_P(str2, T_STRING)) {
VALUE tmp = rb_check_funcall(str2, rb_intern("to_str"), 0, 0);
if (RB_TYPE_P(tmp, T_STRING)) {
result = rb_str_cmp(str1, tmp);
}
else {
return rb_invcmp(str1, str2);
}
    }
    else {
result = rb_str_cmp(str1, str2);
    }
    return INT2FIX(result);
}
```

But the above code I couldn't understand.But I beleieve it has the answer how `nil` is producing when `LHO` is not the object of class `Symbol`.

Can anyone help me here to understand how the `nil` is coming when `LHO` is not `sym`?

Comment: Look closely, is not `rb_str_cmp_m(rb_sym_to_s(sym), rb_sym_to_s(other))` that is returning the `nil` is the line above: `if (!SYMBOL_P(other)) {
        return Qnil;
}`

Comment: @fmendez yes see closely that `other` is `RHO`. I am talking about `LHO`. It first checks the `RHO` if `sym` or not. If `RHO` is `sym` then it just invoke return statement with calling `to_s` on both `LHO and RHO`.

Comment: Perhaps you're confused in thinking that <=> is an operator (hence you talking about LHO and RHO). It's not really an operator, it's a method (hence you should be talking about receiver and arguments). The LHO is the receiver. I've expanded my answer to clarify.

Comment: @AlexChaffee Yes I know its a syntactic sugar. Leave that operator and looking into the source code will give the actual answer.The doc is a bit confusing here. source code is the only option to get the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symbol and String are different types, and as such are not comparable, just like Fixnum and TrueClass are not comparable. See [Why are symbols not frozen strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085564/why-are-symbols-not-frozen-strings) for a rant about how they really *should* be the same (i.e. the case for making class Symbol inherit from class String).

In your first example, the method `<=>` is being called on a symbol, and the argument is a string, so `sym_cmp` returns nil.

In your second example, the method `<=>` is being called on a string, and the argument is a symbol. So the `rb_check_funcall` sees if it can be naturally converted into a string using `to_str`; it can't ("NoMethodError: undefined method `to_str` for :bar:Symbol"), so (eventually) `nil` is returned in that case too. (We'd have to dig in and see what `rb_invcmp` does to flesh out that "eventually" there :-))

Comment: But do you think the documentation is correct for `nil` looking at source code. I think document is not clear.

Comment: As I read the C source, it's saying "if the other one isn't a symbol, return nil, otherwise convert them both to strings and compare them," which seems correct.

Comment: now your update is on the right track. I have given the github link you can use it.